# Rollback EF Core migration from multiple databases

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, migration, npgsql

I've got multiple databases with same tables and architecture for different clients, I'm using EF core 6.0. For migrating the databases I'm using simple function which requests all database names and for each database connection is opened and `Migrate()` function called.
Snippet:

```
var databaseNames = ... //database names

var connString = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString(nameof(DbContextMaster));

Parallel.ForEach(databaseNames, databaseName =>
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContextMaster>();
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connString.Replace("[databasename]", databaseName), SetupMigrationTable);
    var context = new DbContextMaster(optionsBuilder.Options);
    try
    {
        context.Database.OpenConnection();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        // catch logic
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Database.CloseConnection();
        context.Dispose();
    }
});
```

I'm looking for similar functionality but for rolling back last migration, is there a way to achieve this or is removing only achievable manually from cli?

Comment: Check [this article](https://makolyte.com/ef-core-apply-migrations-programmatically/). You have to select appropriate migration and call `IMigrator.Migrate(desiredMigration)`

Comment: I tried this approach but I'm getting an error ```"Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "SomTable" already exists"``` which makes me think that, ```IMigrator.Migrate(desiredMigration)``` might just be running Up() function for the specified migration

Comment: Looking at [dotnet ef code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/85ef284f18c5b998d3088c14bc42a09a34993eae/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/MigrationsOperations.cs#L197) - same thing.

Comment: @user13490951 `desiredMigration` must be the one **before** the migration you want to rollback (or special value "0" to rollback all). It's basically the migration argument of `Update-Database` PMC command.

Comment: Tested on different databases and it indeed works, but the one I was interested in refused to do anything on ```IMigrator.Migrate(desiredMigration)``` or "0", so I had to manually roll it back. Thanks for the article thought, will be useful in other cases